# cannot resolve symbols 'SQLiteDatabase' in android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I've encountered a problem with Android Studio. When I create a database class file at that time, I get an error like, cannot resolve symbol'SQLiteDatabase'.
I used Android Studio version 3.5.2 before doing the right thing, but after I update the system problem downloaded the same version again, since then the problem is coming into the database class file.

My database Class file

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBmain extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBmain(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable android.database.sqlite.**SQLiteDatabase**.CursorFactory factory, int version) {//**error cannot resolve symbole 'SQLiteDatabase'**
        super ( context, name, factory, version );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(android.database.sqlite.**SQLiteDatabase** db) {//**error cannot resolve symbole 'SQLiteDatabase'**

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.**SQLiteDatabase** db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {//**error cannot resolve symbole 'SQLiteDatabase'**

    }
}
```

build Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

> edit

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBmain extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBmain(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super ( context, name, factory, version );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must import `SQLiteDatabase` also:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
```

and then you can remove all `android.database.sqlite.` from the declarations of the `SQLiteDatabase` objects:

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBmain extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBmain(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super ( context, name, factory, version );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: @pintu then you are not using the code correctly.

Comment: I just imported the method,

Comment: @pintu copy and paste the class as it is in my answer.

Comment: The SQLiteDatabase file is not imported.

Comment: sir, I imported but the same error is fetched.

Comment: @pintu check if you misspelled the imported class. It must be: `import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;` If the problem persists run File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Comment: @pintu although the code you have is not exactly as it is in my answer you should not get any error. Probably there is a problem with the imported class file. Try to upgrade to a newer version of AS (current version is 4.2.1).

Comment: Ok, sir, I am grateful for your support.